# get list which start with entry string and after give all results which is available in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

hear i give table, i want list which statues is start with entry after one entry row is available and remaining list is return.......

```
id  did      date         statues
35  853 10/21/2016 0:09     trip
38  853 10/21/2016 0:48     Entry
39  853 10/21/2016 1:00     Exit
41  853 10/21/2016 1:48     trip
42  853 10/21/2016 2:10     Entry
43  853 10/21/2016 2:22     Exit
46  853 10/21/2016 3:16     trip
47  853 10/21/2016 3:55     Entry
49  853 10/21/2016 4:08     Exit
52  853 10/21/2016 5:16     trip
53  853 10/21/2016 5:41     Entry
54  853 10/21/2016 5:54     Exit
56  853 10/21/2016 7:09     trip
57  853 10/21/2016 9:21     Entry
59  853 10/21/2016 9:32     Exit
61  853 10/21/2016 10:24    trip
62  853 10/21/2016 10:46    Entry
64  853 10/21/2016 11:01    Exit
67  853 10/21/2016 11:51    trip
68  853 10/21/2016 12:21    Entry
```

Comment: give query for it....

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We won't give the query for it unless you show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

select * from table_name where id>(select min(id) from table_name where statues like '%entry%');

Comment: working now SELECT * FROM cyclelog WHERE id<>(SELECT id FROM cyclelog WHERE statues LIKE 'trip' AND DATE>20161021000000 LIMIT 1) AND did=853 AND DATE>20161021000000;